# When is using Task.Run wasteful or delusional?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have an interface that reads/writes an object to storage. In one case the storage is a database with async methods. In the other case it's just a cookie.

I gather that its recommended to use async back along the path ending at an async call, so it seems to make sense for the interface to be async as well. But in the cookie case, I'm just setting a couple fields and sticking it in the response so there isn't any async there yet. I can wrap that bit in await Task.Run() to match the new interface but I don't know if this is advisable or if it has some negative impact on performance.

What to do?

```
public interface IProfileStore
{
    async Task SetProfile(UserProfile profile);
}

public async Task SetProfile(UserProfile profile)
{
    // Look mom, I'm needlessly async
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var cookie = new HttpCookie(AnonymousCookieName);
        cookie["name"] = profile.FullName;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    });
}
```

Comment: Well, what exactly are the odds that you are going to be able to notice your code occupying a TP thread for 30 nanoseconds?  Cookies usually work with network connections that have a *million* times more latency than that.

Comment: @James I don't think you can use the `async` modifier on an interface method.

Comment: Have a look at the articles on [my `async-await` curation](http://curah.microsoft.com/45553/asyncawait-general).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not do that; you're just creating needless threadpool churn.

Instead, remove the `async` keyword from the method and simply `return Task.FromResult(0)` to return a synchronously-completed task

Comment: This is changing the exception handling semantics such that exceptions won't be wrapped in the returned task.

Comment: @Servy It isn't uncommon for task returning method to throw exceptions synchronously. Take `Task.Delay` for example...

Comment: @I3arnon I didn't say it was wrong, merely that he's changing the semantics.  If the user wants those altered semantics, that's their decision.

Answer (score 1):

If you're performing a very short quickly completed operation then you're quite right that there is likely no need to use `Task.Run` to push the work to another thread.  The act of scheduling the code in the thread pool is likely going to take longer than *just doing it*.

As for how to do that, just remove the `await Task.Run` that you have no need for and voila, you're all set.  You have a synchronous operation that is still wrapped in a `Task` and so still matches the required interface.

Comment: Then you'll get a compiler warning.

Comment: @SLaks Yes, you will.  But since you'll know your code is correct, you can safely ignore it.

Comment: @SLaks More than a compiler warning, this has the whole overhead of  an `async` method including building the state machine which isn't necessary here.

Comment: @I3arnon It adds some work at compile time; but given that it's not actually awaiting the overhead is purely the creation of one object instance; that's just not really expensive at all.

Answer (score 1):

Almost as SLaks suggests if you were doing something async but return the Task, so:

```
public Task SetProfile(UserProfile profile)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var cookie = new HttpCookie(AnonymousCookieName);
        cookie["name"] = profile.FullName;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    });
}
```

However as he suggests in this case:

```
public Task SetProfile(UserProfile profile)
{
    var cookie = new HttpCookie(AnonymousCookieName);
    cookie["name"] = profile.FullName;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    return Task.FromResult(null);
}
```

Return null as its a system cached completed Task.